# Fetching linked model content separately in Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to load a linked model from Bim360 Docs in forge viewer.

I am able to see all linked content when I load the parent/root model.

So, When I load the root model in the viewer, after that I want to implement functionality, where I can turn on/off the visibility of linked models from Forge Viewer.

For example, If I am loading a Root model having 2 models linked to it, child1 and child2, It will load content from Child1 and Child2 as well.

In this case, If I want to see content from Child1 only, how can I tell the viewer to hide all content/elements from the child2 model?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing it sounds like the output of the translation (the SVF file generated by the Forge Model Derivative service) includes the root model as well as all the linked files "baked" into one a single scene, is that correct? In that case the linked models should be part of the "instance tree", appear in the Model Browser panel, and you could use the [Viewer3D.prototype.hide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#hide-node-model) method to hide these subtrees based on their dbIDs.

Alternatively, if you know the dbIDs beforehand, you can pass in an options object to the [loadDocumentNode](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options) method to only load specific dbIDs, for example:

```
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, geometry, { ids: [4, 5, 6] });
```

Comment: Yes, You are correct, when we upload the model in BIM360 docs, we don't need to do the translation process manually, BIM 360 docs does it for us. We can see the content of different linked model in the model browser, but it is grouped under various categories/object families, to hide an entire model from that, how do I know which category/object family belongs to which model?  Can I retrieve linked model data from the root model in forge? If no, can you please suggest any different approach?

Comment: My understanding was that linked models would appear at the top of the instance tree but I may be wrong. If you have no way of detecting which objects in the tree represent which model, another option - although more complicated - would be to try and break the links, upload & translate each model individually, and then only aggregate the models you are interested in using the [multi-model](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher) functionality.

Comment: The AECModeldata gives us the information of linked documents. The function is - Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(doc.getRoot()). If this function is called on root model, we can get how many documents are linked to the root model, and some "documentId" and "instanceId" for each document. Can you please tell me, can we leverage this information to distinguish the elements as per their source files after linked in a root model?